# basic jquery .load with loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why the home.html links `<a>` is not working?

Is there any thing I  must do in html pages ?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load(getHash(), function() {
        $("a").click(function () {
            var page = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
            $("#content").load(page);
      });
    });
});
</script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#home.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>
```

home.html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#page.html">page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the # from the href values.

Comment: I believe thats what hes using the substring for